# Unable to Import Susy in SASS / Compass

Tags: node.js, sass, npm, atom-editor, susy

I don't know how to connect the atom.io editor with susy.

I have tried searching the "atom susy", "atom susy sass" and simmiliar in google, but I have found nothing that help me. (most result were connected with chemistry, so I started to write "atom.io" instead of "atom" and this still has not delivered good results)

Okay... So I have:
Atom (editor) with packages:

1. sass-autocompile
2. sass-watch

and npm with:

1. node-sass
2. susy
3. auto-loader

I have tried:

```
@import "/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/susy-2.2.12/sass/susy"
```

But susy doesn't work.

```
@import "C://Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/susy-2.2.12/sass/susy"
```

But susy still doesn't work.

```
@import "susy"
```

Error (not found)

```
@import "~/susy/sass/susy"
```

Error (not found)

```
@import "~/susy-2.2.12/sass/susy"
```

Error (not found)

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work?

Am I missing config? (if yes: Where to write this config?)

Comment: check where the gem is "where gem"

Comment: It is  _C:\Ruby22\bin\gem_ and _C:\Ruby22\bin\gem.bat_ ach... I see, I have to enter relative path to this exec

Comment: Nope, relative path to it in "linux" style doesn't work

Comment: Make sure your config.rb has line require "susy"

Comment: I think my config.rb is being ignored. I placed it in the same folder with the .sass file.

Comment: place it in the root of project folder

Comment: install compass as well like gem install compass --pre

Comment: Yea, I am doing that right now ;) "sass watch"

Comment: check my answer which is with compass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to make sure whether you installed properly.

#### Install Compass

```
gem install compass --pre
```

#### Install Susy

```
gem install susy --pre
```

#### Create config.rb in the root of the project folder.

```
# Add the below contents
require "susy"

project_type = :stand_alone
http_path = "/"

# your sass folder
sass_dir = "sass" 
css_dir = "css"
images_dir = "img"
fonts_dir = "fonts"
javascripts_dir = "js"
line_comments = false
preferred_syntax = :scss
output_style = :expanded
relative_assets = true
```

#### Create main.scss

```
// Add the below contents
@import "susy";

body {
 background: #000;
}
```

> *Watch through compass now -* "**compass watch**"

Comment: Thanks for great answer! If I have folder like "proj" and in it is the folder "style" with "main.sass", I have to place config in "proj" or "style"?

Comment: root means proj folder